# Saving spark dataframe in a table databricks - An error occurred while calling o22944.saveAsTable

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

Context: I'm loading data using sql, doing a transformation and then saving this dataframe (converted using Pandas API on spark) to a spark dataframe. I'm then trying to save this spark dataframe as a table on a database, but I get an error

```
sql_selection = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
df_final = ps.DataFrame(sql_selection)
spark_final = df_final.to_spark()
spark_final.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("data.table")
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22944.saveAsTable.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

The causes are these:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 43.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 43.0 (TID 194) (10.139.64.4 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.

Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'ValueError: [E109] Component 'tok2vec' could not be run. Did you forget to call `initialize()`?'. Full traceback below:
```

Comment: post bigger stacktrace, especially lines `Caused by`...

Comment: from error it looks like that you're usign Spacy transformers or something like, but didn't initialize environment.  If in `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table")` the `table` is temporary view, then the problem is in the code that generates that view

Comment: Indeed I'm using spacy for a text cleaning setup in azure databricks. The `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table")` is a table that is present in azure databricks (hive_metascore). I don't quite understand what it means by "initialize environment" (I'm quite new to azure databricks). Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spacy, just seeing that error is coming from it: `ValueError: [E109] Component 'tok2vec' could not be run. Did you forget to call initialize()`